# Variable as vee validate v-validate directive value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate, vue-directives

I'm using Vee validate for from validation, validation rules are coming from backend and passed to component data in following format:

```
"rules": {
    "password": "{ required: true, regex: /(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}/ }",
    "old_password": "required"
 }
```

How can i use rule from data in v-validate directive?

```
<input name="password" ref="password" v-model="password" v-validate="rules.password">
```

this syntax give me an error `No such validator ''{ required' exists.` Looks like vue is parsing the v-validate value somehow

p.s. for validation rules which are simple strings it works ok

```
 <input name="old_password" v-model="old_password" v-validate="rules.old_password">
```

Comment: did you try `v-validate="rules.password.required"` ?

Comment: it will not work, i need to pass whole string `{ required: true, regex: /(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}/ }` as validation rule

Comment: `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: I believe the problem is that the value of `password` is a String instead of an Object

Comment: @Giovane you are right, if the value is object it works as expected. but I don't really understand why :(  My assumption is that `rules.password` are not really inserted in html, but processed as js variable

Comment: Yeah, it should, but as you are passing it's value as a String, the js won't guess that this string is actually an object

Answer (score 0):

changing "password" to Object solved the issue. Thanx Giovane for his comment.

```
"rules": {
    "password": { "required": true, "regex": "/(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}/ }",
    "old_password": "required"
}
```